# Changing dielectric for a PCB antenna

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

We have designed and tuned a prototype PCB antenna on a high-frequency, low-loss material.  We now have to move to a less expensive material for production.  Any guidance on length tuning of the antenna elements with this change in Dk?  My searches to date have been less than fruitful.

Comment: IMHO you should apply a rule of three with regards to the wavelength (as in "distance").
When scaling an antenna from one frequency to another, one has to scale the lengths accordingly.
As you change your dielectric, the wavelength changes - I would start by scaling the antenna size accordingly.

Comment: Did the old design come out of thin air? It shouldn't be too hard to follow the same principles and calculations that created that, but with a different material...